# Lexicon of ‘undesirable’ words?

Tags: nlp

Is anyone aware of an NLP lexicon or dictionary that can be used to screen for undesirable words in professional documents?   For example abusive or discriminatory words, or sexual terms?   Any tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search reveals some resources that may be of use to you:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/resources/

https://pypi.org/project/profanity/ (if you're coding in Python)

https://www.noswearing.com/dictionary (construct your own)

You might also want to include some regular expressions (e.g. `.*fuck.*`, `.*shit.*`) to account for productivity and creation of new words that may not be in those lexicons. But careful with this as you will probably want to avoid flagging other words as profanity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a general corpus, but you could do sentiment analysis on specific words and just say "any word w/ negative sentiment worse than threshold is a word I don't want"